pseudo element nesting css doesnt apply using `&` for ::marker under <details> but <summary>
trying CSS nesting feature with pseudo element ::marker but found it strange that this nesting does not work
 details {
      padding: 4px;
      & summary {
        color: red;
        & ::marker {
          color: green;
        }
      }
 }


while this works

details {
      padding: 4px;
      & summary {
        color: red;   
      }
      &::marker {
          color: green;
        }
 }


below is my  code snippet to run


details.default{
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-left: 1rem solid #f16db9;

  & summary {
    color: red;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &::marker {
    color: green
  }

}


details.other {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-left: 1rem solid #f16db9;

  & summary {
   color: red;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    &::marker {
      color: green;
    }
  }

}
<details class="default">
  <summary>default question</summary>
  <p>default answer</p>
</details>

<details class="other">
  <summary>other question</summary>
  <p>other answer</p>
</details>



so does ::marker is a part of <summary> or <details> here? while in inspect Element it show under 


This is just a typo - there is a space (ie a combinator) before ::marker in the second setting - which means you are looking for a child of summary rather than summary::marker. [Side note: the green does not show at all on Safari/IOS17...]

removed space but still no impact.

You've removed the space from before both the ::markers. It's only the second one that should be removed. Tho' I don't see how there was no impact at all [removing both the spaces shd. have shown the second marker as green]. What browser and OS are  you on?  I'm seeing both markers as green on Edge/Windows10  if there's a space before the first one and none before the second one.

checked in firefox and chrome both with latest version. can you please post code snippet as answer to check and identify issues in my code.

I’ve put up the answer. Do you still have the problem?

On my Edge/Windows10 this snippet makes both markers (the arrows) green.
Note the spaces are important. We need one when the marker is being formatted separate from the summary and we don't have one when it is being formatted as part of the summary in the nesting.


details.default {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-left: 1rem solid #f16db9;
  & summary {
    color: red;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  & ::marker {
    color: green
  }
}

details.other {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-left: 1rem solid #f16db9;
  & summary {
    color: red;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
    &::marker {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
<details class="default">
  <summary>default question</summary>
  <p>default answer</p>
</details>

<details class="other">
  <summary>other question</summary>
  <p>other answer</p>
</details>



Also tested on FF and Chrome on Windows10 and in both cases the arrows are green.
On Safari (IOS17...) the arrows are red altho' caniuse says marker is OK. Is it the nesting that is the problem?

it looks like fix but let me check and get back to you as I have ubuntu 24.04

oh. so single whitespace even matters and considered here . Thanks.

Yes, it’s still a combinator. Difficult to spot.
